# Using HighCharts in a model

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've used high charts throughout my project but want to now use it in a ViewModel here:

```
using WAD_Tracker.Models;
using DotNet.Highcharts;

namespace WAD_Tracker.ViewModels
{
    public class DistanceGoalViewer
    {
        public Distance Distance { get; set; }
        public Highcharts Chart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I keep getting this **error** that says:

> HighCharts is a namespace but is used like a type

but [this tutorial](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2014/05/09/how-to-include-dotnet-highcharts-in-asp-net-mvc-with-viewmodels/) shows that it is possible.

Comment: plz, read the documentation you linked, you need to follow the steps.

Comment: @Ferus7 The only thing ive done differently is install highcharts 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public Highcharts.Highcharts Chart { get; set; }
```

Try this

Comment: The type or namespace name in "Highcharts" does not exist in the namespace 'HighCharts'

Comment: Can you open the intellisense of vs when you dot  Highcharts  namespace? ??

Comment: it shows up as UI, Core, MVC. When I dot.UI it gives me the list of type of graphs(I want a line graph) so i've chosen Hightcharts.UI.LineGraph and all the errors go away.

Ill accept your answer :)